# Linux Ubuntu 16.04. - ClamAv problems

Tags: 16.04

Since I  upgraded Linux Ubuntu from the version 15.10 to 16.04. obviously ClamAv doesn't work correctly. When I deinstall all ClamAv files and ClamTk and install all again, then it works just one time. Does anyone have the same problem and found a solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Some details about what isn't working properly and any error messages will greatly increase your chances of getting any help.

Comment: „sudo apt-get update“ shows:
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/landronimirc/clamtk/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/landronimirc/clamtk/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

„sudo freshclam“ shows:
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).